# Calling custom directive in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to do something like that, Can it be possible in angularjs

```
ng-change=\"myDirective = [test]\"
```

i.e. I simply want to call my directive on `ng-change` , is it possible in angularjs to call custom directive inside directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible but for doing this you need **another directive for watching changes** on your `myDirective` variable...

when you change value of `myDirective` middleware directive catches changes and **rebuild dom**.

I created such a directive for another problem but it can be used in your situation so I edit this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/F8TqVWfHF3uNunVTUVRH?p=preview) for you...